# How to get all XML elements in PHP (including supplementary information inside tags)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML code that I grab from an external site:

```
<source>
  <url>http://externalsite.com</url>
  <widget id="1">
    <title>Title1</title>
  </widget>
  <widget id="2">
    <title>Title2</title>
  </widget>
  <widget id="3">
    <title>Title3</title>
  </widget>
  <widget id="4">
    <title>Title4</title>
  </widget>
  <widget id="5">
    <title>Title5</title>
  </widget>
</source>
```

**How would I get the `id` and `title` of each widget in PHP?**

Comment: I've tried `simplexml_load_file` but can't figure out how to get the `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [worked for me](http://viper-7.com/3tNgkP):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xml);
foreach( $xml->xpath( '//widget') as $el) {
    $attributes = $el->attributes();
    $children = $el->children(); // OR: $el->xpath('title'); if children vary
    echo $attributes['id'] . ' ' . $children[0] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: by the way the php docs dont give a proper example on how to use simplexml. Thanks for bringing up this !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [`xpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php for more information.